# Row-wise union of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have two `DataFrames`'s:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('A', 0.3), ('B', 0.4)], columns = ('ID', 'Buy'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([('B', 3), ('A', 4)], columns = ('ID', 'Sell'))
```

That yield:

```
    ID  Buy
0   A   0.3
1   B   0.4
```

and

```
    ID  Sell
0   B   3
1   A   4
```

respectively.

Now, I want to obtain a single `DataFrame` that collects the data, namely:

```
    ID  Buy  Sell
0   A   0.3  4
1   B   0.4  3
```

Note that the order of the lines in `df1` and `df2` may not be the same. Furthermore, there might ID's that appear only in one frame and not in the other --- in this case the missing value should be filled with `NaN` I guess.

How can I do it?

I tried something like

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], join = 'outer', axis = 1)
```

but doesn't return the desired result.

Comment: Is `df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='outer')` what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) on `ID` column:

```
In [12]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame([('A', 0.3), ('B', 0.4)], columns = ('ID', 'Buy'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([('B', 3), ('A', 4)], columns = ('ID', 'Sell'))
df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='outer')
Out[12]:
  ID  Buy  Sell
0  A  0.3     4
1  B  0.4     3
```

Comment: If I have more `DataFrame`'s similar to `df1` and `df2`, can I merge them directly, or only iteratively?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean, if you mean if you have more than 2 dfs you can just iteratively merge them all

Comment: So there is no `merge([df1,df2,...,dfn])` but only `df1.merge(df2.merge(...(dfn)))`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I did look at `concat` which does take a list of dfs but the result is not quite what you want as it will introduce a hierarchical index or level in the columns which is not what you want.